# Jquery bind & ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery code, I am trying to **//Do things** every time the page is reloaded/refreshed and when the select box is clicked. But when I add the ready function (as in document is ready,) yet what is supposed to go inside **//Do things**, only gets executed with a click event, but not ready.

How can I fix this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("select").bind("change ready", function(){
         //Do things
      });
```

Comment: this *is* stack overflow (outdated comment about needing to be moved to SO)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply pull out the code into another function, and call that both on page load and on change:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var func = function() {
        // do things
    };

    // this does things whenever the <select> changes
    jQuery("select").on("change", func);

    // this does things once, when the page loads
    func();
});
```

I also changed `bind` to the recommended `on` instead (as of jQuery 1.7) -- this does not change the behavior at all.

Comment: what happens if there are more then one select box, and do things refers to what the select has for value?

Comment: @voigtan: I don't think that's a meaningful question based on the (little) information the OP has provided. I 'd be happy to reconsider when more information is forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the .[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method in jQuery, you want to trigger the function in your bind event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("select").bind("change", function(){
        //Do things
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: If there are many select boxes this will call the handler *multiple* times on page load. Not sure if that's what the OP intends.

Comment: @Jon I may be wrong, but if the OP wants to trigger the same event on "ready" event then this the result is that he wants to trigger all the select boxes on a document.

Answer (score 1):

The `document.ready()` function waits until your whole document is loaded and the dom tree is built. Thats why it is a good idea to wrap your code within the `document.ready()`. If you didn't do this, it might happen that your call `jQuery("select")` does not find any element, because there is no domtree yet.

Now if you want to `//Do things` when clicking upon your `select` elements, you can either:

```
jQuery("select").click(function(){

});
```

or

```
jQuery("select").on("click", function(){

});
```

This binds a handler for a click-event to **each** of your `select` elements.

Check out the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        // do your anything
    });
});
```